# this.props in component does not contain navigation property

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to navigate from one screen to another by `this.props.navigation.navigate('Second Screen')` but property 'navigation' does not contain in the props. Get error:
Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import styles from "./style";
import { Keyboard, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableWithoutFeedback, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class SignInScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.containerView} behavior="padding">


        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.loginScreenContainer}>
            <View style={styles.loginFormView}>
              <Text style={styles.logoText}>Book Market</Text>
              <TextInput placeholder="Email" placeholderTextColor="#c4c3cb" style={styles.loginFormTextInput} />
              <TextInput placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor="#c4c3cb" style={styles.loginFormTextInput} secureTextEntry={true} />
              <Button
                buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
                onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                title="Login"
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me your entire code?

Comment: @hongdevelop I updated my question with a new part of the code.

Comment: use  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I find a solution. At first, I need to change extends of my class like

```
export default class SignInScreen extends Component<{navigation: any}>
```

Then change onPress action:

```
<Button
  buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
  onPress={() => this.onSignInPress()}
  title="Login"
/>
```

```
private onSignInPress() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only access it through the parent element. Pass navigation as a prop to its children to use it

Eg:

```
<Child navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Comment: Like you would pass any props. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do what was already suggested, pass the navigation prop down to your target component

Ex:

```
<TargetComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Or you can use `withNavigation` HOC from react-natigation.

Ex:

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'

...

export default withNavigation(Child)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since the problem of undefined *navigation* property still exists at least for those who use EXPO managed approach, I'll write my solution hopefully it'll save someone's day.

After searching for hours I found no way to fix this bug and find a way to add *navigation* property to *this.props*. Finally, I solved the problem by using *NavigationContext* in this way:

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <NavigationContext.Provider>
        <Stack.Navigator>
            ...
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContext.Provider>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then get the navigation in a consumer:

```
<NavigationContext.Consumer>
    {navigation => {
        return (
            <Button onPress={() => this.onButtonPress(navigation)} />
        );
    }}
</NavigationContext.Consumer>
```

And finally:

```
onButtonPress(navigation) {
    try {

        navigation.navigate(RouteNames.FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_SCREEN);

    } catch (e) {
        this.setState({ errors: [e.message] });
    }
}
```